# How to translate a javascript code snippet using `Array.from` to Parenscript (Common Lisp library)?

Tags: javascript, common-lisp, primitive, parenscript

I have this code snippet working on the browser using JavaScript:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))
```

The`document.querySelectorAll('input')` gets a NodeList and `Array.from` converts it to an array.

I am trying to translate it to Parenscript inside a function as:

```
(ps:chain  array (from  (ps:chain document (query-selector "input")))))
```

This is close:

```
"array.from(document.querySelector('input'));"
```

There is even a little trick to achieve the capital letter with the hyphenating of `-array`:

```
(ps:ps   (ps:chain  -array (from  (ps:chain document (query-selector "input")))))
```

Which generates:

```
"Array.from(document.querySelector('input'));"
```

But it does not work as expected when called. It returns an empty string.

How can I fix it?

Obs.: I am using Common Lisp/SBCL.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by »when called«?  How do you call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Parenscript only returns primitive values which are:

1. Undefined;
2. Boolean;
3. Number;
4. String;
5. BigInit; and,
6. Symbol.

The code `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` is not returning a
string, it is returning some objects. That's why it fails to work.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).